# Issue Running Console App using a Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I created a console application in `VS2012` which, by itself compiles fine. I published it on a local network and made a shortcut on another computer on the network. When I run the app by double-clicking the shortcut OR by executing via the command line I get the error:

> "Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted."

Details provide the following information:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of Y:\Errol\CommodityVolJob\ConsoleApplication2.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///Y:/Errol/CommodityVolJob/ConsoleApplication2.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Manifest XML signature is not valid.
        + SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
```

Comment: this `ConsoleApplication2.application` means that you are using ClickOnce, right? As I remember `.application` is just a manifest, do you have your executable near this manifest? And are you sure that you have the same version of .NET Framework?

Comment: @outcoldman I'm running it on a computer that has a Microsoft.NET folder (but i don't see any version). I imagine that means it has the .NET framework. 

I'm not sure where the executable is. When I publish this, I don't see any executable in the folder that contains the manifest/shortcut.

Comment: 1. You need to make sure that you have the same version of [.NET Framework installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx) on the machine where you want to launch this app. 2. Just build application and copy ConsoleApplication1.exe to your share (if you don't have any dependencies on third party dlls).

Comment: If you are trying to run this on an XP machine then you'll need to mention that.  As well as the target .NET version you selected.